# wxwidgets wxlistctrl edit specific column

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

OS: WIN 8

WX VERSION: 3.0.2

Having problem with wxListItem - wxListCtrl:
I have a wxListCtrl with 2 columns and with the following masks: wxLC_REPORT | wxLC_EDIT_LABELS | wxLC_SINGLE_SEL | wxLC_HRULES | wxLC_VRULES

Problem: I want to edit the labels in the 2nd column by mouse click but at the moment, a mouse click anywhere in a specified row only edits the 1st column.

why is that? what would I need to do to edit only the 2nd column and prevent column 1 from being edited?

I have checked the official documentation, but there is not much info on the mask, as I would like to think this might be a problem related to improper use of the appropriate MASK

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wxListCtrl` only supports editing of its first column due to the same limitation in the native list view control used to implement it under MSW.

If you need all columns to be editable, consider [wxDataViewCtrl](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0.2/classwx_data_view_ctrl.html) or [wxGrid](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0.2/classwx_grid.html). Unfortunately neither of them is native under MSW (see [this table](http://www.tt-solutions.com/img/slides/tables_comp.pdf)), but wxDVC doesn't look too bad, especially with the latest versions.